# How to set div element value which is comes from input field using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display input field value in div element. When user click on submit button i want get input field value display in div.
Here is my code,

```
<form onsubmit="add_value()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email address:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="remember"> Remember me</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>

function add_value()
{
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var pass = document.getElementById('pwd').value;
    var chek = document.getElementById('remember');
    var add = document.getElementById('ele_val');
    add.innerHTML = email;

}
```

Comment: You have to add a div with id = ele_val

Comment: yes i have all ready  added div element with id in the html but forget to in my question.
hear is my all code

<div id="ele_val"></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see below snippets.

```js
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  var email = document.getElementById('email').value,
      pass = document.getElementById('pwd').value,
      chek = document.getElementById('remember'),
      add = document.getElementById('ele_val');
   add.innerHTML = email;

  //for testing purposes
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email address:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="remember"> Remember me</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    <div id="ele_val" style="color:red;"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks sir @ Dilhan Jayathilake

Answer (score 1):

**The accepted answer shows the best solution of the given problem.**

But if you want to use inline (which is not recommended), you can do as following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
    function check_validation()
    {    
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        var pass = document.getElementById('pwd').value;
        var chek = document.getElementById('remember');
        var add = document.getElementById('ele_val');
        add.innerHTML = email; 
        return false; // return true if validation is okay!
    };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form onsubmit="event.preventDefault();check_validation();">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email address:</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" id="remember"> Remember me</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <div id="ele_val"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

where you can add your logic in `check_validation()` method to perform validation. If the user input is not okay then return `false`. Otherwise return `true`. Hope it helps!